# Why is my bootstrap modal not showing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I do not know why my modal is not displaying.

I have a link that directs to `images#show`. However I want to use bootstrap modal to display the image instead of reloading the page.

Here is my link that is supposed to display a modal when clicked on. The link

```
- url = @entry.class.to_s.downcase.singularize
= link_to(send("#{url}_path", @entry), data: { remote:true, 'type' =>    @entry.class.to_s.downcase }) do
    = yield
```

The link is in my `home#index`.

Here is my `images#show` controller:

```
def show
    authorize! :view, @image
    @can_destroy = can?('delete_asset', @image)
    @can_edit = can?('edit_metadata', @image)

    respond_to do |format|
       format.html
       format.js
       format.json
    end
```

My _modal view template is :

```
<div id="contact-modal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      ...
      Moussa Testing the Modals
      <div class="modal-body">
        Me testing again
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        Moussa testing encore.
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I added a show.js.erb in the image views for ajax:

```
$('<%= j render "modalview" %>').modal();
```

The modal is not displaying however.

Comment: other bootstrap js related behaviors works? maybe the js didn't load? have any errors in the console?

Comment: I did not see any errors.